# Enterprise Root CA create CodeSigning Certificate for Multiple Users

Tags: certificate-authority, development

Is it possible to have a root CA in the enterprise create a CodeSigning certificate (to be used in a Visual Studio solution) that is registered to more than one user? The way it is now, I am the only developer that can publish our solution because the certificate signing the manifests is linked to my account.

Please forgive me if this is common knowledge, but my searches haven't come up with anything useful. Windows Server 2008 R2 and with Windows 7 clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the way you want.
There are few options:

**1)** issue a personal signing certificate to each developer. Assign CodeSigning certificate template to CA and grant permissions to dev group.

**pros:** each developer has his own signing certificate.

**cons:** too many certificates. May be ok for internal (development and testing) purposes only. Is not suitable when you deliver signed binaries to your customers or other 3rd parties.

**2)** issue a single certificate to developer groups. Export to PFX and provide a copy of this certificate to all devs.

**pros:** only one certificate is used for signing. Best suitable to sign binaries for external parties.

**cons:** you are not controlling who signed the file. You see it is signed by a particular certificate, but can't tell who exactly signed the file. It is security degradation.

as per best practices, products for external parties shall be signed by a single and authorized digital certificate that identifies the company. This certificate shall not have copies and should be stored in a secure container, for example smart cards. However, for internal use and if your policy allows this, I would go with option 1, to issue personalized code signing certificates to each developer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Option two seems to fit the best with our requirements. Everything is internal to an intranet enterprise network, so really, our only concern is being able to have any developer publish using the same CA issued cert. 

We're working with a single application that only allows a single certificate to sign the assembly, so option 1 is out. I just wasn't sure if you could generate a certificate based on active directory group memberships.

Comment: Be aware about significantly reduced security, as the certificate (and its key) is out of control. You can't guarantee key privacy. Yes, you can duplicate existing Code Signing template and change subject to supply in request. You will be able to put any custom subject name in the certificate.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton for the help. Really, it's more about getting WPF to play nice with the manifest signature so we can make use of full trust application capabilities. Code security isn't really a factor in this case.